# itextsharp add text above of chunk image

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I want to get some text in above of my image.  my code like this :

```
 Dim pdfcb As PdfContentByte = Writer.DirectContent
                        Dim code128 As New Barcode128()
                        code128.Code = partnumber
                        code128.Extended = False
                        code128.CodeType = iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CODE128
                        code128.AltText = ""
                        code128.BarHeight = 13
                        code128.Size = 6
                        code128.Baseline = 8
                        code128.TextAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
                        Dim image128 As iTextSharp.text.Image = code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(pdfcb, Nothing, Nothing)

                        Dim phrase As New Phrase()
                        phrase.Font.Size = 10
                        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(phrase)
                        cell.FixedHeight = 68.69F
                        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
                        cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE
                        cell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER
                        phrase.Add(New Chunk(Environment.NewLine + "Companyname"))
                        phrase.Add(New Chunk(Environment.NewLine + "address"))
                        phrase.Add(New Chunk(image128, 10, 30))
                        phrase.Add(New Chunk(Environment.NewLine + partnumber))
                        phrase.Add(New Chunk(Environment.NewLine + "111"))
                        tbl.AddCell(cell)
```

I am always getting my address and company name below of my image.
i want to make that in above of my image
What i can do for that? any help is very appreciable.

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Why are you using a `Phrase`? Why are you adding the content to the `Phrase` *after* creating the `PdfPCell`? That's all very, very strange... It's as if you've never read the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/).

Comment: i am using Itextsharp Version 5.5.8.0.actually sir i got this code from google search,then i try to print barcode,barcode is printing.but i want to add some text in above barcode,that s what i am trying to do..but not working

Comment: Good coders learn how to code from the documentation. Other coders use Google search to find code they can copy/paste. Please take a look at my answer and you'll understand that you didn't search well enough. The exact same question as you're posting now was answered on January 26, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PdfPCell` in [text mode](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/text-mode). You shouldn't do that if you want to add an `Image`. Use `PdfPCell` in [composite mode](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/composite-mode) instead:

```
Dim cell As New PdfPCell(phrase)
cell.FixedHeight = 68.69F
cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE
cell.AddElement(New Paragraph("CompanyName"))
cell.AddElement(New Paragraph("Address"))
cell.AddElement(image128)
cell.AddElement(New Paragraph(partnumber))
cell.AddElement(New Paragraph("11"))
tbl.AddCell(cell)
```

Note that I removed the following line:

```
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
```

In composite mode, you need to change the alignment of the elements that you're adding. In this case: you need to change the aligment of the `Paragraph` objects (that's fairly easy to accomplish). See [Alignment, indentation, leading and spacing in cells](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/indentation-cells), [How to use multiple fonts in a single cell?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-use-multiple-fonts-single-cell) and [How to right-align text in a PdfPCell?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-right-align-text-pdfpcell)

Your question is also an almost exact duplicate of the question [How to put text above a bar code instead of under the bars?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-put-text-above-bar-code-instead-under-bars) which was posted on StackOverflow on January 26, 2016 (little over a month ago).

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. See [How to put text above a bar code instead of under the bars?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-put-text-above-bar-code-instead-under-bars) The bar code is displayed correctly without any problem.

Comment: @Bruno you seem to have mixed some c# in your answer...perhaps tidy that up?

Comment: @Bruno The New keyword should be capitalized, and yes, VB is a real language, capable of everything C# is, without most of the punctuation.  SO is no place for language fanboyism.

Comment: @MrGadget OK, now I've removed the `;` and made `New` uppercase. Are there any other vb.net specific things I should be aware of?